# What does "中" as an independent verb means?

Tags: verbs

I found one 明星 saying this on Youtube: "我中了，我中了." ； https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4egudxwbdI  (4:27)。I have tried asking this to tutor online, and he answered: 中 means:
-to hit (the mark)
-to be hit by
-to suffer
-to win (a prize, a lottery)
And gave me a website that states exactly that, but doesn't have an example for the independent use and meaning of 中. So, I wonder, what does 中 mean in such context?  Can 中 act as a verb in itself??

Answer (score 2):

**中 = to win**:

中獎 = win a prize

中頭獎 = win the first prize

中大獎 = win the grand prize

中安慰獎 = win the consolation prize

中二奬 = win the second prize

中彩票 = win lottery

中頭獎彩票 = win the lottery jackpot

中二獎彩票 = win the second prize lottery

*獎 in 中獎 is always referring to prize by chance; Not to be confused with 得獎/獲獎 (win award) which the prize or award is always on merit*

**中 = to take/ be hit by**:

中槍 = 1. take/ hit by a gunshot; 2. take (hit by) a (long) spear trust

中彈 = take/ hit by a bullet strike

中刀 = take/ hit by a knife strike

中劍 = take/ hit by a sword strike

中錘 = take/ hit by a hammer strike

中拳 = take/ hit by a (fist) punch

中腿 = take/ hit by a (leg) kick

*take/ hit by any object above cause harm, therefore, 中 can also be understood as 'to suffer'*

**Example in longer sentence**:

今期彩票誰中? - who won the lottery this time?

旗艦中了三枚魚雷下沈 - The flagship took (was hit by) three torpedoes and sunk

Notice:

As an adjective or a noun 中 is pronounced as /zhong1/ in Mandarin and /zung1/ in Cantonese

As a verb, 中 is pronounced as /zhong4/ in Mandarin and /zung4/ in Cantonese

Comment: OP also wants to know of "...an example for the independent use and meaning of 中"?, i.e what does 中 means on its own?

Comment: I already stated 中 means " to win; to take; to be hit by" e.g.[ 中] 流星錘 =  [take] a  流星錘 strike; [中]兩次彩票 = [win] lottery twice; 今期彩票誰[中]? who [won] the lottery this time?

Comment: To add to this answer, I think it's also worth mentioning that as a verb it's pronounced with the 4th tone (zhòng) whereas as an adjective it has the 1st tone (zhōng) - in 普通话 at least.

Comment: Do the given examples work in both Mandarin and Cantonese?

Comment: Yes, my examples work in both Mandarin and Cantonese. See http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/62/

Answer (score 1):

I remember this being used standalone in the recent-ish Confucius movie with Chow Yun-fat. There is a scene with an archery competition where it is used when hitting the target in the centre.